# Parallax Jquery .css function with .background-position-y

Tags: jquery, css, firefox

i have a parallax that work with this function

```
var scaleBg = -$(window).scrollTop() / 3;
if (iOS === false) {
            $('.payoff').css('background-position-y', scaleBg - 150);
            $('.payoff2').css('background-position-y', scaleBg - 150);
            $('.social').css('background-position-y', scaleBg + 200);
        }
```

This not work on firefox becouse the background-position-y is not supported, how i can solve this for firefox?

Comment: I'd make it a 'normal' background-position and add the value for whatever has been set for the x-axis.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the combined `background-position` property such as:

```
var scaleBg = -$(window).scrollTop() / 3;
if (iOS === false) {
    var payoffY = scaleBg - 150;
    var payoff2Y = scaleBg - 150;
    var socialY = scaleBg + 200;
    $('.payoff').css('background-position', '0px ' + payoffY + 'px');
    $('.payoff2').css('background-position', '0px ' + payoff2Y + 'px');
    $('.social').css('background-position', '0px ' + socialY + 'px');
}
```

Just for reference here the `+` is for concatenation not addition. The `0` is what ever you need the `x` position of your background to be.

This should be a more cross browser compatible way of assigning background-position.

Comment: Thank you, now work.
I was close to this solution, my mistake was to use scaleBg directly as y value, but did not work.

Comment: Glad it worked. If you are happy with the solution please select this as your accepted answer.